# Xaml сериализация без событий

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, события, сериализация

Помогите пожалуйста с xaml сериализацией, как мне сделать что-бы сохранялись ссылки на всякие события, всё работает идеально, но только без событий не чего не собирается реагировать ☹️

Может быть я не правильно как-то сериализую?

Сериализация :

```
        savedcanvas = XamlWriter.Save(canvas);
```

Десериализация (наоборот) :

```
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(savedcanvas);
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
        Canvas loadcanva = (Canvas)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
```

Comment: Контролы и не должны проходить полноценную сериализацию\десериализацию.

Comment: @Monk не повезло  :(